# Windows 10, how to upgrade node from 0.10.26 to latest (6.10 or 7.7.1)

Tags: node.js

The official node documentation says just run the installer from the latest version and it will overwrite the old version. It doesnt in my case for some reason.

```
node --version
```

gives 0.10.26.

I downloaded and installed 6.10.0 LTS from the node site.

node --version still gives 0.10.26 (including after reboot)

I have read many posts on the subject, and other people suggest

```
  npm install update
```

this downloads some files, but node --version still gives 0.10.26

In add-remove programs, there is only 6.10.0, no 0.10.26, so dont know how to uninstall this old version.

Any ideas where I can get an uninstaller from, or how to manually uninstall the old version?

Note, I dont want to complicate things with one of the many tools for managing multiple versions of node as this is likely to add more complexity and problems, I just want to get the latest node if that is possible.

Searching my hard drive, i found there is nodejs installed in program files.  Its not easy to know what version this is, but the CHANGELOG.md says version 3.1.0.  I have no idea where 0.10.26 is installed to, nor 6.10 for that matter.

I cant see anything like NODE_HOME in my env vars, but c:\programfiles\node\nodejs is in the PATH.  Although add-remove programs tells me 6.10 is installed, I dont see how or where, or how to uninstall 0.10.26

Any ideas?

=== update ====

To make it even more confusing, I tried CDing into c:\program files\nodejs and ran "node.exe --version" This DOES give 6.10.0.  So the only version of node which seems to be on the machine, and the one my path points to, is 6.10, but when I run "node --version" in any other directory, I get 0.10.26.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by luck, I found the problem. I went through every item in my path and found something called baboonstack, which I had never heard of.  Uninstalled that, and get 6.10.0!  Good times!